# Can't create a directory in a Sagemaker Endpoint? Error Read-only file system

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm deploying an endpoint using a Pytorch model, in the input_fn I have the following:

```
os.mkdir('outputs')
os.mkdir('outputs/assets')
```

At the end of the outpu_fn I remove the `output` folder

But when invoking the endpoint I get the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'outputs'
```

Am I not allowed to create a folder in `/opt/ml/model` ?

Comment: can you try os.makedirs('outputs') here is the reference  https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/frameworks/pytorch/code/test_inference.py